# dynamic generate m3u8 list with EXT-X-BYTERANGE

Tags: http-live-streaming, m3u8

I want to fetch hls video segments by time interval.
Suppose I have seg1.m4s / seg2.m4s ..., and each seg is 1 minutes long and size is 10000 bytes.
If I want to play from 1:30 ~ 3:30, it means the hls would start from middle of seg2 to middle of seg4.
This why I would need to dynamic generate m3u8 list and EXT-X-BYTERANGE.
However I encounter some problem.
Here is my m3u8 list now

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="init.mp4",
#EXTINF:30.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:5000@5000,
seg2.m4s
#EXTINF:60.0,
seg3.m4s
#EXTINF:30.0,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:5000@0,
seg4.m4s
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

It would play only seg2.m4s and stop.

Comment: The offsets must start at a valid point in the mp4. Preferably at a moof box. Not just a random byte.

Comment: thanks for your comment. How can I find valid point in mp4?

Comment: Parse it and locate the moof boxes.

Comment: thanks it works now! I would share my solution later.

Comment: @鄭元傑 It's been more than 1.5 years, would you please share your solution?